# Wrapping ellipsized text with quotation marks in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I use `android:ellipsize="end"` in the XML for a TextView that contains long texts.

Because this text is a user comment, I want to wrap the ellipsized text into quotation marks. When I use

```
commentView.setText("\"A very very looooooooong text.\"");
```

the output is

> "A very very loooo...

But I want it to be

> "A very very loooo..."

I can't ellipsize the string first and then wrap it into quotation marks, because I don't know the actual width of the view beforehand. Any suggestions?

Comment: What about android:ellipsize="middle" ?

Comment: Ok, this generates "A very ve...oong Text". It doesn't look cool, I think.

Comment: If it not looks cool for you, I suggest to count how many symbols you want to show in runtime. You can easily find a way how to determine screen size and it's density. Relying on that information you can count how many symbols you can show.

Comment: were you able to to do it?please provide an answer